# CSS :after pseudo element doesn't work inside button in any IE version

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I can't get this code to work in any IE version. Am I doing something wrong or is IE just crap as usual?

**HTML:**

```
<button>A button</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
    position: relative;
}

button:after {
    content: "Can u see me?";
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    top: 0;
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/96ryusnp/

Comment: Strange: IE9 and up should support it correctly. IE8 has partial support. See https://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/

Comment: I've tried IE10 and IE9 here on my virtual box. None of them is working. Please try for yourself if you have the possibility. Piz.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add `overflow: visible` to `button`.

```
<button>A button</button>

button {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}

button:after {
    content: "Can u see me?";
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    top: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/96ryusnp/1/

IE must set it to `hidden` by default on buttons.

Comment: Worked perfectly. So nice to find a simple solution to an IE problem every once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

`button` elements are replaced elements.

And according to the [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/generate.html#before-after-content),

> This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before
>   and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be
>   defined in more detail in a future specification.

But the [current draft of Selectors Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#gen-content) only says

> The ::before and ::after pseudo-elements can be used to describe
>   generated content before or after an element's content. They are
>   explained in CSS 2.1

Therefore, using `:before` or `:after` on `button` elements will produce unreliable results.

Comment: As far as I know, this is incorrect; a `button` is a non-replaced element.

Comment: @DaanMortier You can set the sizes of a button even if it has `display: inline`, which should only happen for replaced elements. One could argue that what happens is that the button binding forces it to be displayed as an inline-block, and that's why it works, without needing to be a replaced element. It's hard to say, because this is not fully defined and different browsers do different things. Let's say it's a  ["kinda-replaced" element](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Mar/0190.html).